# Getting error 'Constants.platform.ios.model' has been deprecated in favor of expo-device

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting the following error in my new project Expo React Native. please guide:
"WARN  Constants.platform.ios.model has been deprecated in favor of expo-device's Device.modelName property. This API will be removed in SDK 45."

Comment: related?: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15110#issuecomment-1625077724

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try updating to the latest version:
*expo-cli upgrade* or *npm audit fix --force* both of these worked on my end